# Angular 5 - Microsoft Graph - Error 401 while requesting resource for OneNote

Tags: angular, http, microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I have a problem requesting resources from Microsoft graph (for OneNote API). I am not sure I am obtaining access token correctly. I use implicit flow as it is for the Angular 5 front end application.

Token obtaining with url according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit :

```
window.location.href = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?'
      + 'client_id=' + CLIENT_ID
      + '&response_type=token'
      + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT_URI
      + '&scope=' + SCOPE
      + '&response_mode=fragment';
```

I am using scope 'Notes.ReadWrite.All' also according to docs and it seems to work fine, as I get token after login.

This is the way I am trying to request notebooks:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-type': 'application/json; ' + 'charset=utf-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN,
    });
    this.http.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v2.0/me/onenote/notebooks', {headers: headers}).subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
```

But I keep ending up with error:

```
status: 401, 
statusText: "Unauthorized"
code: "InvalidAuthenticationToken", 
message: "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049403"
```

It feels like there is trouble parsing the token, or the token is simply incorrect. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, I have done this using 2 calls. The first call

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

returns the **code** that you then can use, to further request the access token.

So after this initial authorization - I have used the following endpoint to request for the access token:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

while providing the original code received after authorization, along with that request. As a response to this, you will receive the actual access token (and a refresh token to use after token expiry). This you can further use for your actual data requests (it is valid for 60 minutes).

More details here:
[Microsoft Graph - get access on behalf of a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user)

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. But now I am getting missing CORS headers error. Is there any way to solve that?